# Can i Use JsonP using post method in google closures?

Tags: closures, jsonp

> i am using the following code to send a request in jsonp using google closures and i want to  > send the contents only using Post method and i want to know how it send, from the formed url > it seems like its sending via normal get method
>
> Here is my code

```
var url = "http://myurl/";
var jsonp = new goog.net.Jsonp(url);
jsonp.send(
{"name":"jessi","action":"initaction","gameId":"123"},
 callback, callbackfailed);
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible to POST using JSONP.

`<script>` tags cannot send POST requests.